# stopping link_to when clicking on a span inside a div

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I am working on a project which has a link_to around a div, which routes to the specified discussion when clicked. However, I also added a span inside the div that acts as a "bookmark" button which uses some javascript to bookmark that discussion when pressed. However, it is also activating the link_to and routes the page to the discussion page. Is there any way I could have it so that the link_to doesn't activate when the user clicks on the span?

```
<%= link_to discussions_path(discussion_id: discussion.id) do %>
  <div tabindex="4" class="discussion-item row">
    <h4 class="discussion-item-title">
      <%= discussion.title %>
      <% if current_user %>
        <span class="change-icon favorite-discussion" 
          data-id=<%=discussion.id.to_s%> 
          data-fav=<%= @favorite_discussions.include?(discussion) %>>
          <% if @favorite_discussions.include?(discussion) %>
            <i class="fa fa-star pull-right" id=<%="star#{discussion.id}"%>></i>
          <% else %>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o pull-right" id=<%="star#{discussion.id}"%>></i>
          <% end %>
          <i class="fa fa-star pull-right"></i>
        </span>
      <% end %>
      <div class = "discussion-item-date pull-right">
        <% if discussion.created_at > Time.now.beginning_of_day %>
            <%= time_ago_in_words(discussion.created_at) %> ago
        <% else %>
            <%= discussion.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </h4>
    <p class="discussion-item-description">
      <%= discussion.content %>
    </p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is definitely not HTML, looks like ERB to me.

Comment: Thanks I added that tag.

Answer (score 0):

First: I would not nest the span inside the link, BUT if you are set on that or cannot change it...

I am guessing you are using jquery. When you use JS for the bookmark link/span you can use this:

```
event.preventDefault();
```